# Android Emulator SocketServer and Client

Tags: android, emulation

I am trying to write a TCP server that listens on the loopback address and a client that connects to it. Both reside within the emulator. Since this is only using the loopback address. Should this still need firewall forwarding rules to be set in the android emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it shouldn't need firewall rules but if you're using 'localhost' in the emulator, you should read this...

[Referring to localhost from the emulated environment](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias)

Comment: Thanks. I think I will bind to 127.0.0.1 since I want to bind to the emulator's interface. And this should work on the device as well right ?